# Capturing/Return the output message of python logging

Tags: python

Is there a way of obtaining/returning the message from a call to logging.debug()?

Thanks

Comment: You should tell us something about the context: Did you write the logging code yourself or do you want to intercept log messages from another module/framework/whatever?

Comment: hi das, The reason I ask is that I launch (using subprocess.Popen) a number of child processes (c++ programs) and create a python logger for each.The output from each process is logged to each processes logger. I wanted to have a 'master' log, which contains the output of each process , so that each entry in the master log contains the logger name of each process as an identifier

Answer (score 4):

Yes, providing a mechanism to easily capture and redirect event details without requiring any modification to the code emitting the events is the entire purpose of the `logging` module.

All you need to do is include an appropriate call to [`logging.basicConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging#logging.basicConfig) as your application starts up and you can send logged events wherever you wish.

The simplest is to just log to `stdout`:

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

For more advanced options, I suggest checking out the [logging tutorial](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) in the official documentation.

If you want programmatic access to the formatted message at the point of making the call... then the `logging` module is the wrong tool for the job. It is designed for emitting events, not for use as an alternative to calling `str.format` directly.

For the case you describe in your comment, you may want to consider a [hierarchical logging](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#loggers) setup along the following lines:

```
>>> import logging
>>> import sys
>>> logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> master = logging.getLogger("master")
>>> child1 = logging.getLogger("master.child1")
>>> child2 = logging.getLogger("master.child2")
>>> child1.debug("Event from child 1")
DEBUG:master.child1:Event from child 1
>>> child2.debug("Event from child 2")
DEBUG:master.child2:Event from child 2
```

In this setup, note that I only configured a handler at the root level of the hierarchy (as part of the `basicConfig()` call). `logging` understands the "parent.child" notation in logger names, so it will pass any events passed to the child loggers up to the master logger, which in turn passes them on to the root logger.

You can add additional logging handlers at the `master` and `child` levels as necessary in order to redirect the output wherever you wish.

Comment: thanks ncoghlan. The reason I ask is that I launch (using subprocess.Popen) a number of child processes (c++ programs) and create a logger for each.The output from each process is logged to each processes logger. I wanted to have a 'master' log, which contains the output of each process , so that each entry in the master log conatins the logger name of each process as an identifier

Comment: Updated my answer - hierarchical logger names should do exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Well, logging.debug usually writes to a file. you can read that file by using the `open()` function.

Comment: You can leave out ".exe" for Windows as well. This will store all the output to that txt file.

Comment: @khchik: I trashed my first answer, cause I got the question all wrong

Comment: `logging.debug()` only write to a file if you configure them to do so.

Comment: @ncoghlan: Added "usually" ;)

Comment: Well, true, that's usually a sensible way to have it configured. I'm guessing from the phrasing of the question that it hasn't been configured at all in this particular case, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace `logging.debug` at startup?

```
import logging
d = logging.debug
def myDebug(*args):
  print "I'm a spy", args
  d(*args)
logging.debug = myDebug
```

Comment: NEVER do this. There is absolutely no good reason to be monkey-patching the logging module, given the huge level of configurability it provides natively.